# Including range is multi-part numbers

Tags: siunitx

How do I produce something like "4 x 5 x (10--15) mm^3" in *siunitx*?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX!] (http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `siunitx` handles units, not mathematics (although `\SI{}{}` is provided to match simple numerals with units). Is this something you're looking for? `$4 \times 5 \times (10-15) \si{\cubic\milli\meter}$`?

Comment: I wouldn’t use a `--` here as it may be mistaken for a minus sign. What do you think of `$\num{4} \times \num{5} \times \SIrange[range-phrase=\ldots, range-units=brackets]{10}{15}{mm^3} $`? Of course this should be done in an own macro.

Comment: Forget whatever I said, @Qrrbrbirlbel knows his stuff way better than I do.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel any particular reason to "\num{4}" instead of directly "4" in math mode? I can't tell any difference in the output...

Comment: @Leo Well, you wanted to use `siunitx` … In this simple case there is no difference, of course. Though, it will be better to use `\num` in other cases and complex numbers.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Package `siunitx` also supports expressions with multiple parts for the number. However, a range as number is not supported then. The following example uses a quotient instead and locally reconfigures, how quotients are printed. The second expression also adds the brackets that are a bit trickier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \SI[
    product-units   = power,
    input-quotient  = :,
    output-quotient = \text{--},
    quotient-mode   = symbol,
  ]{4 x 5 x 10:15}{\mm}

  \newcommand*{\myrange}[2]{%
    (%
      \numrange[
        range-phrase  = \text{--},
        parse-numbers = false,% numbers are ready for printing
    ]{#1}{#2})%
  }
  \SI[
    product-units     =power,
    input-quotient    =:,
    quotient-mode     =fraction,
    fraction-function =\myrange,
  ]{4 x 5 x 10:15}{\mm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t use an en-dash here as it may be mistaken for a minus sign. You can define a macro `\mSIrange` that uses `\SIrange` but set ups `\ldots` (or `\textendash` if you insist) as the `range-phrase` and activates also the brackets `( )`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand*{\mSIrange}[1][]{\SIrange[range-phrase=\ldots,range-units=brackets,#1]}
\begin{document}
$ 4 \times 5 \times \mSIrange{10}{15}{\milli\metre\cubed} $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]